# SMPP: User data header Concatenated SMS

Tags: sms, client-server, concatenation, sms-gateway, smpp

I'm new in SMPP, I read that in concatenated SMS user data header field which contains sequence number used to concatinate different parts of SMS.
My question is: Can this field be duplicated for different SMSs? Or it should be unique?
I faced problem in parts concatenation when this field duplicated. But it length is really small (4 octet) so it will be duplicated in case of large number of SMSs being sent!
Can you please give me more information about this field?

Comment: Field 4 of the UDH is the CSMS reference number and must be the same for all parts of the concatenated message but unique from other SMS messages. Field 6 is each parts sequence number and must be unique.

Comment: Are you sending that many messages to the same MT/Device?

Comment: I'm sending them to different devices as a result of executing specific services in a system. The problem is that I have huge number of SMS, so I don't think having limited values for the message identifier is a good option, since there is a probability for duplication if a customer executes multiple service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSMS reference number only has to be unique among SMS messages sent to the same handset. The purpose is for the handset to be able to separate different incoming concatenated messages from each other when assembling their parts.